# Why does inline-block ruin my positioning?

Tags: css

I'm fairly new to CSS, and I'm having trouble figuring this out. Here's my main div:

```
.blocksContainer{
position: relative;
border: solid;
height: 150px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And here is the child div:

```
#blocks{
border: solid;
height: 85px;
width: 85px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 32.5px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Here is my first HTML example:

```
<div class="blocksContainer">
     <div id="blocks">Test</div>
    </div>
```

Here's my result, works great:

[image]

The blocksContainer class spans the page and the individual block will remain centered throughout as I want. However, when I add another block, I get this:

[image]

Obviously not ideal. So I tried to use the inline-block rule on the blocks class and get this:

[image]

It messed up my center positioning and no matter what I do I can't get the blocks centered. I don't want to have to make the blocksContainer class a set width because this will be used on many different screen sizes, unless I can center that div and then each block with it.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: put them both inside of another div and then center that div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the text-align:center; from the child container to the parent container. This in turn will center your containing inline-block elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/wv8sT/

### CSS

```
.blocksContainer {
    position: relative;
    border: solid;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.blocks {
    border: solid;
    height: 85px;
    width: 85px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 32.5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Very odd, there is definitely something that is pushing it to the right:

http://i.imgur.com/G8pml6y.png

Is there a way I can respond to this and provide my entire CSS to see if there is anything else pushing it that I'm unable to find?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with the issue you mentioned?

Comment: So the problem is with your .logoBar container. It has a height of 60px + margin top 15px, total 75px. The height of the parent wrapper is 60px. This causes your logobar to drop down into your .blocksContainer wrapper throwing the positioning of the containing elements off.